# Geopandas causing dead kernel

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, spyder, geopandas

Currently trying to do some work with geopandas but when I try to use it either causes a dead kernel on Jupyter Notebook or the kernel to restart on Spyder.

I'm running Python 3.8.1, iPython 7.22.0, Jupyter Notebook 6.4.0 and Spyder 4.2.5 through Anaconda 2.0.3. I'm on a M1 Macbook Pro running macOS Big Sur version 11.0.

This is the first instance of using geopandas in my script:

```
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
```

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: How did you install GeoPandas?

Comment: @martinfleis conda install -c conda-forge geopandas

Comment: Can you report it to https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues? It will be easier to find an issue there. It is likely some kind of an installation issue.

Comment: @martinfleis will do. currently reinstalling anaconda to see if that works. if not, will post there. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geopandas now works on my machine.

The quickest way around it was to create a new environment with geopandas like so:

```
▶ conda create -n geo-env -c conda-forge geopandas
```